# using BCP command with sql server Local DB

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, localdb

I'm trying to use bcp on a sql server local db database.  First off does bcp even work on local db?
If i try to use this command on a regular sql server database.

```
exec master.dbo.xp_cmdshell 'bcp db.dbo.table out c:\test\results.txt -w -T -S <server>'
```

it works fine..no errors
if i then change the server to `localhost\(localdb)\v11.0` it says it cannot find the instance. ive tried looking all over the net. i'm wondering how to get this to work with Local DB . any help would be appreicated

Comment: try without the localhost. just -S ‘(LocalDB)\v11.0’

Comment: Tried that without localhost and just (localdb)\v11.0  still can't find it wtf

Answer (score 6):

For SQL Server LocalDB 2016, use the following:

```
bcp YourDBName.dbo.table out c:\test\test.txt -w -T -S (localdb)\MSSQLLocalDB
```

Answer (score 1):

You must specify the path where the mdf file is located.
This works for me in sql localdb 2012:

```
bcp [c:\path_to_db\db.mdf].dbo.table out c:\test\test.txt -w -T -S (localdb)\v11.0
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're connecting to a local sql server, just leave out the -S and the server.
BCP will take the default instance which is the localhost.